# Testing using an upgraded VS2012 solution, but building in VS2010

Tags: coded-ui-tests

So I've downloaded VS2012 RTM and upgraded my Coded UI test projects to the VS2012 versions.

The reason I have done this is because I was having issues with VS2010 Coded UI tools due to partial support of IE9.

So I ran the tests from my developer machine both locally and remotely (making use of the new Visual Studio agent tools), and the tests worked successfully. Presumably, the reason my tests now work is that VS2012 upgraded them so that they now work with IE9, right?

So - this is my problem. I want to automate these tests, by launching them from our build machine - but our build machine still runs on VS2010, and for the time-being this is not going to change.

So I checked in my new VS2012 Coded UI test solution into TFS and queued a new build - so the build machine built my solution. And the build was successful. All good there.

So, next I created a new test case in Microsoft Test Manager and associated with the ordered test list in my new solution. Then I launched the tests (using the existing VS2010 test controller) on my remote test environment (which has the existing VS2010 test agent tools).

But the tests failed - the same issues that affected my tests with the VS2010 Coded UI tests (due to lack of full support for IE9)

Why did they fail?

Do I need the new VS 2012 agent tools for my test controller and agents? Must I build my solution in VS2012?

Ideally, I don't want to have to install VS2012 RTM on my build machine - I want to do the minimum possible to get my tests working and automating.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coded ui tests reference assemblies that come with VS installation or your agent's installation (the assemblies defininf the WpfControl, Mouse, Keyboard, Playback and other classes).

So if you run it on a build/test machine with older versions of the dll's the same issues are going to stay, the tests will not start using the newer fixed assemblies thatt were shipped with VS2012.

As a temporary workaround you can check what dll's you reference and make sure that the build process puts them in the same directory with your tests assembly. That way the lookup for them will find the in the current directory without using the /path and finding them in the VS installation directory.

Comment: The agent installation? You mean the Visual Studio test agent software (test controller and test agents)? 

Does the test agent software contain the coded UI test engine?

Comment: Okay so I think I have figured it out then. 

I noticed that when I load the VS2012 solution up in VS2010, the Coded UI reference assemblies are switched to the VS2010 versions. 

So it looks like MSBuild.exe does not switch the DLL references, and instead looks for the DLL references in the path which doesn't exist in the build machine (in the Visual Studio 11 folder).

Comment: Now, what confused me was why it worked successfully previously. The reason for this was because I had actually installed the Visual Studio 2012 RC agent tools on the build machine, which I assume carries the coded UI test DLL's - therefore the DLL references worked then. I had since uninstalled the agent tools (because Microsoft Test Manager 2010 doesn't work with the 2012 agent tools), so that's why it stopped working. 

This also explains why the tests did not work properly - because they were running against the VS2010 Coded UI test engine (using those DLL's). 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your coded ui test project you are referencind dll's like this one:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll so when trying to locatel the same dll on the test machine it will find the older version

Comment: One thing I tried but doesn't seem to work is that I have installed the VS2012 agent tools, and placed the VS2012 DLL's into the Visual Studio 11 folder on the build machine - thus the VS2012 DLL's will be in the same location as on my developer machine, however my builds still failed when built via TFS.